# Change child of iOS Container View from child interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, childviews

I have a Container View that contains a view. I want to change this view to another, calling a method of the parent view when the user interacts with an object of this child view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let say the container is a class named 'ContainerView' and it has a function called 'changeSubView'
from the child view you can call it using:

```
let containerView = self.superview as! ContainerView
containerView.changeSubView()
```